# Convert THREE.js scene to CANNON.js world

Tags: three.js, blender, scene, cannon.js

I have a basic `THREE.js` scene, created in `Blender`, including cubes and rotated planes. Is there any way that I can automatically convert this `THREE.js` scene into a `CANNON.js` world ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Three.js Blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender), it looks like it only exports mesh data, no information about mathematical shapes (boxes, planes, spheres etc) that Cannon.js needs to work. You could try to import your meshes directly into Cannon.js, using its [Trimesh](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/6c6aff9fc2ccafd18c905b1e2b64eaf62663e398/src/shapes/Trimesh.js) class, but this would sadly [only work for collisions against spheres and planes](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/#features).

What you need to feed Cannon.js is mathematical geometry data, telling it which of your triangles in your mesh that represent a box (or plane) and where its center of mass is.

A common (manual) workflow for creating 3D WebGL physics, is importing the 3D models into a WebGL-enabled game engine (like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/), [Goo Create](http://goocreate.com/) or [PlayCanvas](https://playcanvas.com/)). In the game engine you can add collider shapes to your models (boxes, planes, spheres, etc), so the physics engine can work efficiently. You can from there preview your physics simulation and export a complete WebGL experience.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for this great engine which helped me a lot on my project ! While working on the solution, I came across another problem : The Cannon planes seem to have no limits. How can I limit the planes so that I can implement some kind of triangular prism ?

Comment: Nice to hear that it was useful for you!
If you want a square plane, use a box instead of a plane. If you want a triangle prism, then construct a Convex. Maybe you can even use a Cylinder with very few segments.

Answer (score 1):

Going to post another answer since there are a few new options to consider here...

1. I wrote a simple `mesh2shape(...)` helper that can convert (one object at a time) from THREE.Mesh to CANNON.Shape objects. It doesn't support certain features, such as heightmaps/terrain.

Example:

`var shape = mesh2shape(object3D, {type: mesh2shape.Type.BOX})`

2. There is a (experimental!) [BLENDER_physics extension](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf/tree/master/extensions/BLENDER_physics) for the glTF format to include physics data with a model. You could add physics data in Blender, export to glTF, and then modify THREE.GLTFLoader to pass along the physics data to your application, helping you construct CANNON.js objects.

Comment: where can I find the mesh2shape function you wrote? (your account has been inactive for a year, I doubt I'm getting an answer)

Comment: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-to-cannon found it